# How to get a list of all the buffers in elisp?

Tags: elisp, buffers

I am trying to get a list of buffers through elisp. So I created the following function:

```lisp
(mapcar (function buffer-name) (buffer-list))
```

This works when I do something like:

```lisp
(minibuffer-message (mapcar (function buffer-name) (buffer-list)))
```

However, the following line of code does not work:

```lisp
(insert (mapcar (function buffer-name) (buffer-list)))
```

**Q:** Could this just be a noob mistake? Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`insert`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Insertion.html#Insertion) takes an arbitrary number of strings or characters as arguments, so it bails when you hand it a list of strings.

Try this:

```lisp
(insert (mapconcat (function buffer-name) (buffer-list) " "))
```

Or this:

```lisp
(apply #'insert (mapcar (function buffer-name) (buffer-list)))
```

Comment: +1 for `mapconcat` – it's bailed me out of a tough situation countless times